# How to rearrange words in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem for which I can't find a solution any where. I'm a newbie here and I hope somebody can answer my question. I have a excel sheet with data in the following format.

- Samsung Note 4 Book Cover
- Book Cover Samsung Galaxy S3
- Note 3 Samsung Book Cover

Like this I have over a 1000 items but I want to rearrange the words in this manner.

- Book Cover Samsung Note 4
- Book Cover Samsung Galaxy S3
- Book Cover Samsung Note 3

Please let me know how I can rearrange the words to get the result like this.

Comment: Is *Samsung Note 4 Book Cover* all in one cell or spread out over several cells??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please show us what you have tried, where you have looked for solutions, and where you have run into problems.  Also please read Help for how to ask a good question, and how to supply a good example of your problem.  As written, your problem is easily solved by removing `Book Cover`; then concatenating at the beginning of the residual string.  That, of course, will only work if the only phrase you are interested in is `Book Cover`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,10)="Book Cover",A1,CONCATENATE("Book Cover ",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-11)))
```

Note A1 is the column of the data in snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substitue to replace "Book Cover" with nothing, ie remove it, then put it at the beginning using the & to concatentate it at the start.

```
="Book Cover " & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Book Cover","",1)
```